# index.js:1 Warning: A context consumer was rendered with multiple children

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I simply try to use react provider but somehow i get this error: index.js:1437 Warning: A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a child that isn't a function. A context consumer expects a single child that is a function. If you did pass a function, make sure

index.js:1 Warning: A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a child that isn't a function. A context consumer expects a single child that is a function. If you did pass a function, make sure there is no trailing or leading whitespace around it.

```
function MiveJat() {
  const consumer = React.useContext(abAnarContext);
  console.log(consumer);
  return (
    <abAnarContext.Consumer>
      <div>GOlabi</div>
    </abAnarContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove for your component <abAnarContext.Consumer>

```
function MiveJat() {
  const consumer = React.useContext(abAnarContext);
  console.log(consumer);
  return (
      <div>GOlabi</div>
  );
}
```

then it will work again